# How can i override abstract class protected function

Tags: magento2, admin, overrides, admin-controller, preference

I want to override abstract class `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create` of the below method

```
protected function _processActionData($action = null){

 }
```

I have tried using preference but it is not working.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Preferences don't work for abstract classes because the abstract classes are never instantiated. But you can use preferences for the classes that extend the `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you share an example of it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a preference to tell Magento which class to use in place of the vendor class `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create` (I suppose you're creating a module named **Module** at the path `app/code/Custom/Module`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectMamager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference type="Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create" for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create"/>
</config>
```

Then, create the file `app/code/Custom/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create as MagentoCreate;

abstract class Create extends MagentoCreate
{
    protected function _processActionData($action = null){
        // here your code
    }
}
```

Finally, run `bin:magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: it is not working hay you checked?